# How to create a soft or symbolic link?

Tags: symbolic-link

I am installing p4v in `/opt`, but `/usr/bin` is on my path.  Is it possible to create a soft or symbolic link for p4v from `/opt` to `/usr/bin`, so I can just type "p4v" since `/usr/bin` is in my path?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1951742/how-to-symlink-a-file-in-linux

Comment: ln -s /path/to/file /path/to/symlink

Answer (score 929, accepted):

See `man ln`.

To create a symlink at `/usr/bin/bar` which references the original file `/opt/foo`, use:

```
ln -s /opt/foo /usr/bin/bar
```

You would need to apply the above command as root (i.e. with `sudo`).

Comment: I am using:   `sudo ln –s /etc/apache2/sites-available/redmine /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-redmine`
getting error: `ln: target '/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-redmine' is not a directory`

Comment: @RAJ...: Perhaps an example can help `ln -s /etc/vim/vimrc /home/paf/Copy/Programming/Apps/Tools/Vim`

Comment: The Ubuntu documentation says " Creates  hard links by default, symbolic links with --symbolic." Will the above solution create a symbolic link as asked by OP?

Comment: I though César wanted to put his files in the /opt and /usr/bin to have the symbolic link, not other way around.

Comment: @mishap is right as far as I'm concerned. It's the other way around.

Comment: Could you explain what is a link that is not symbolic? What is the difference between `ls file ../other` and `cp file ../other`. I was missing the `-s` option for quite some time now and got frustrated...

Comment: @AugustinRiedinger see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/185899/what-is-the-difference-between-a-symbolic-link-and-a-hard-link and http://askubuntu.com/questions/108771/what-is-the-difference-between-a-hard-link-and-a-symbolic-link

Comment: is this answer not backwards????????? not just for the OP, but for anyone trying to use it???

Comment: @Andrew This is correct for creating a symbolic link `/usr/bin/bar` that points to file/folder `/opt/foo`. Per 'man ln`, the target file/folder comes first, then the link name: `ln [OPTION]... [-T] TARGET LINK_NAME   (1st form)`

Comment: @kevinmicke after your explanation finally realized that the explanation of the answer was stated in reverse order from the command, making my brain (and others') read it backwards

Comment: Note that target must be absolute not relative paths

Comment: __NOTE__: Pay attention in creating links with relative paths; you must make the target relative to the link itself, not the directory you're running the command.

Answer (score 62):

The error is that you are writing the command wrong. The correct way is

```
ln -s /<full>/<path>/<to>/<file> /usr/local/bin
```

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2001697

Comment: Note the leading foreslash   `/`

Comment: Thanks, I totally missed that I needed the absolute path to the linked file.

Answer (score 24):

If the 'p4v' executable is at /opt/bin/p4v, you can simply run:

```
sudo ln -s /opt/bin/p4v /usr/bin/p4v
sudo chmod ugo+x /usr/bin/p4v
```

It would be better to add /opt/bin (or wherever the executable is) to your path:

```
echo "export PATH=\$PATH:/opt/bin" >> ~/.profile
reset
```

Comment: `~/.profile` would be better for setting `$PATH`.

Comment: you can edit `/etc/environment` to modify PATH system wide.

Answer (score 6):

Check the software location by this.

```
which application-name #replace for the application you are looking for
```

for example

```
which skype
```

output will be this.

```
/usr/bin/skype
```

To create the soft link. for example you want to create the soft link for `skype` on your desktop

```
ln -s /usr/bin/skype ~/Desktop/
```

For more information about `ln`.

```
man ln
```

or

```
ln --help
```

Answer (score 5):

This template was more helpful for me than the above answers.  Probably not more correct, just less obfuscated:

```
ln -s <path/to/real/file-or-folder> <symlink path>
```

Just replace the parts in `<>`'s

Answer (score 4):

```
ln -s -n ./TargetDirectory ./Nickname
```

---

Note, this works if you both nodes are below you in the same tree. You can use relative notation

- -s command makes it a symbolic link
- -n makes it possible de create a folder-type symlink

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu.com. In this case the `$` to indicate a command line prompt is a style choice, and not likely to be a problem. However bear in mind that including things in a code block other than the code and its output can cause confusion.

Answer (score 0):

If it is saying `target is not a folder`, it means there are spaces in your folder names eg: `New Folder` has a space

You need to edit the path and add a backslash `\` after every space in the paths

eg:

```
ln -s /opt/bin /usr/var/New\ Folder
```

Comment: This is not an answer to the OPs question. Please wait until you have enough reputation to add comments.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that it is easier to go to where you want the link to be and then create the link using `sudo ln -s /path/to/source/file`, than doing `ln -s target source`.

So in your case I would do `cd /usr/bin` then `sudo ln -s /opt/bin/pv4`. The other way has not been working in my case.