# Is it possible for /etc/hosts to include a file from my home directory?

Tags: configuration, hosts

I would like to setup `Ubuntu One` to sync a hosts file in my home directory between my machines.  Ideally I would setup all my local web development URLs there and it would just sync between devices.  But I'm wondering if it's possible for me to setup `/etc/hosts` so that it includes a file from my user's home directory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> But I'm wondering if it's possible for me to setup /etc/hosts so that it includes a file from my user's home directory.

The `/etc/hosts` file is for mapping hostnames to IP addresses before DNS can be referenced. So the answer is no.

> I would like to setup Ubuntu One to sync a hosts file in my home directory between my machines.

Would a [hard link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/108771/what-is-the-difference-between-a-hard-link-and-a-symbolic-link) in your directory to `/etc/hosts` not accomplish that? 
Something like this (where shared-directory will be your synch folder):

```
cd ~/shared-directory/
ln -i /etc/hosts hosts
```

The only difference in approach is that you then share 1 of your actual host files with all the other systems. And not a copy in your home directory.

Comment: Along the same line of thinking with this, it might be worth checking out how some developers handle their "dotfiles" (my personal favorite is [Holman's from GitHub](https://github.com/holman/dotfiles). They generally keep a repository/shared folder somewhere with the files, then symlink them into their home in the filesystem (so reverse Rinzwind's symlink code to be `ln -i hosts /etc/hosts`).