# Does upstart chdir works with symlinks?

Tags: upstart

Currently in my upstart script, `chdir` points to a symlink (soft).

Does chdir respect the symlink or goes directly to the symlinked directory?

The question why I ask this is because in a web server I use (Puma), `pwd` command now using the `chdir` stanza does not point to the symlink directory.

See https://github.com/puma/puma/issues/539 for more info.

Thank you.

Comment: Related: [The difference between a hard link and a soft link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/108771/what-is-the-difference-between-a-hard-link-and-a-symbolic-link)

Comment: @Parto Can you draw any conclusion with soft vs hard link?

Answer (score 0):

Upstart will resolve the symlink. You cannot work around this by using a script section and cd /path.

Edit: it looks like it was figured out what the problem was. `cd` was setting $PWD to the symlink, not the resolved directory, and `chdir` was not setting $PWD at all, so the app was getting its current working directory and receiving the resolved path.