# Why app is still in use despite you have already deleted it

Tags: apt, uninstall, executable

For curiosity, if an app is running (in my case it is indicator-multiboard), I deleted it using `sudo apt purge indicator-multiboard` successfully, however it is still running over the task bar, so I tried `sudo apt autoremove` to see if there is any dependencies, but not.

So why is this happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Programs get loaded into RAM and operate from there (because RAM is faster than hard drives and other storage types). You have uninstalled the app from disk when you did `sudo apt purge indicator-multiboard`, but have not stopped the copy actually loaded in RAM. Once you exit the application, it will be gone from RAM ( although IIRC some cache may remain in swap, which will be gone once those parts of RAM need to be freed up by the system )

If the application `indicator-multiboard` doesn't have an `exit` or `quit` button, you may consider killing the process via `pkill -f indicator-multiboard` or to be safer - find out its actual PID via `pgrep -f indicator-multiboard | xargs ps -p` and then use the PID you find in `kill` command. Of course a simple reboot will have similar effect (on server it's not always possible to reboot, but on desktop it's more than acceptable).

Side note: deleting app from hard drive ( or any file for that matter ) is like removing book from catalog in the library - actual book is still on the shelf until librarian ( the system ) decides to put something else on that shelf and mark it in the catalog.

See also:

- [Linkers and Loaders, Linux Journal](https://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6463)
- [How is rm -rf / able to delete all files in the system?](https://askubuntu.com/a/604329/295286)