# Sync files between folders and keep the latest version

Tags: server, steam, sync

I run 5 Source Dedicated Servers from the same Ubuntu box, and want to make it so the bans and admin lists sync across them all. The bans are stored in the  `banned_user.cfg` and the admins are stored in `admins_simple.ini`.

I have 5 instances of the server software running in seperate folders, and want to keep these files synced across all of the folders. I tried to use a utility called [FreeFileSync](http://www.freefilesync.org) but it ony does one way synchronisation, and I want it to be so if I ban someone on Server 1, the list updates and syncs across to all the other servers.

However, if I ban someone on Server 3, it syncs across to all the other servers as well. 
Like if they were all writing to a single `banned_user.cfg`

I was looking into doing a symbolic link, but it kinda confused me and the documentation was not clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it helps you, symbolic link will keep the path of the file, and hard link will keep the content of the file (a reference to the inode). So in case you delete it the hard link will keep the file, but the modification on the file will be done on the same file.
So, if there are on the same partition, you can do a hard link with

`ln /path/to/your/target/banned_user.cfg /path/to/your/linkname/on/server/2
 ln /path/to/your/target/banned_user.cfg /path/to/your/linkname/on/server/3
...`
if you are on a different partition you'll have to deal with symbolic links with the same principle but with the -s option

`ln -s /path/to/your/target/banned_user.cfg /path/to/your/second/server/banned_user.cfg`

[here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/108771/what-is-the-difference-between-a-hard-link-and-a-symbolic-link) is more documentation about symlinks and hardlinks