# using link command to see how it works

Tags: command-line, hard-link

```
link file1.txt file2.txt
```

`file1.txt` contains `ham` and `file2.txt` contains `cheese`.

I added `123` in `file1.txt`. Now `file1.txt` has `ham123`. If my understanding is correct, any changes made in either file would affect the other, but `file2.txt` is not changed. Why not?

Here's my edition with complete and exact output of my commands:

```
$ ls -li
total 16
1363827 -rw-r--r--@ 1 kim  staff  13 Jan 20 20:09 file1.txt
1363844 -rw-r--r--@ 1 kim  staff  22 Jan 20 20:09 file2.txt
$ cat file1.txt
one
two
$ cat file2.txt
one1
two2
$ link file1.txt file2.txt
link: file2.txt: File exists
$ ls -li
total 16
1363827 -rw-r--r--@ 1 kim  staff  13 Jan 20 20:09 file1.txt
1363860 -rw-r--r--@ 1 kim  staff  10 Jan 20 20:11 file2.txt
$ cat file1.txt
$ cat file2.txt
one1
two2
```

As you can see, I deleted everything inside file1.txt. However, file2.txt hasn't been modified. Both files are in the same directory. I used my text editor to create them.

Comment: I am referring to a hard link, not a soft link.

Comment: Did `file1.txt` and `file2.txt` both exist when you ran `link file1.txt file2.txt`? Are they in the current directory? If they both existed, `link` should have *failed* with `link: cannot create link 'file2.txt' to 'file1.txt': File exists`. Please [edit] with complete and exact output of `cat file1.txt`, `cat file2.txt`, and `ls -li file1.txt file2.txt`. The `-i` flag makes `ls` display a column for inode number, revealing whether or not `file2.txt` was really successfully created as a hard link to `file1.txt`. A hard link is just another name for the file and so always has the same contents.

Comment: @Mint.K: If the command [`link`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/en/man1/link.1posix.html) `file1.txt file2.txt` was successful then it is _impossible_ for `file1.txt` and `file2.txt` to have different contents, because they are just two different names for the same file.

Comment: @Eliah Kagan  I've just edited my post.

Answer (score 3):

**TL;DR:** Making a hard link does *not* create a relationship between different files that causes new changes in one to be reflected in the other. Instead, it creates another name for the *same* file. Your `link` command failed because you told it to create a link called `file2.txt`, but `file2.txt` already existed.

#### Like people and things in world, a file can have more than one name.

Often it is useful to have some way to refer to something. For some things, it is useful to have more than one way. This is not limited to computing.

For example, ["acetaminophen"](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/acetaminophen) and ["paracetamol"](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/paracetamol) refer to [the same medication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paracetamol). It is correct to say acetaminophen is paracetamol and equally correct to say paracetamol is acetaminophen. Neither name *refers* to the other -- instead, they refer to a particular chemical substance, which is not the same thing as any of its names.

Just as a word or phrase may identify a person or thing in natural language, [a *link* -- also called a *hard link*](http://foldoc.org/hard%20link) -- identifies a file, and some files have multiple links. They aren't links to each other, but to the file. (To be precise, what they identify is the file's inode. See below.)

When there are multiple links to a file, it's *not* that the file has one true name and others are false or lesser names. Instead, all links provide names for the file, and none depends on the others. If someone asks you for the name of a file then, no matter which of its hard links you specify, you are equally correct.

#### When you ran `link`, it did not succeed, and no link was created.

When [`link`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/link.1.html) told you `link: file2.txt: File exists`, that was actually an error message. Because a file `file2.txt` already existed, [the `link` command](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_(Unix)) was unable to create a link by that name. Thus `file1.txt` and `file2.txt` are still separate files, and that is how they are able to have different contents.

The `link` command does not create a relationship between separate files. It creates another name for the very same file. That name may be different, or reside in a different directory, or both, but it has the same relationship to the file as its original name. A common though somewhat imprecise shorthand you may have heard for this is that "a hard link *is* the file."

#### Links and Inodes

Although it's intuitive to many users that every file exists in a particular directory and nowhere else, and has just one name, **those things are not true**. Instead:

- The contents of a file may be physically [spread out throughout the disk](http://foldoc.org/cluster).
- [Metadata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metadata) about where to find the file's contents, as well as the [owner, group owner, permissions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system_permissions#Traditional_Unix_permissions), and any [extended attributes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_file_attributes) of the file, are stored in a data structure called an [*inode*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode). (An inode also contains [some other information.](http://foldoc.org/inode))
- For each distinct file there is exactly one inode, and each inode is identified with a number. This *inode number* is the number shown in the left column when you run `ls -li` (and not at all when you merely run `ls -l`). Two different files residing on the same device always have different inode numbers.
- It is useful to be able to think of a file as having a name, and as [residing somewhere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)) in a [directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directory_(computing)) hierarchy. Therefore, a file may have one or more [*links*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_link) (also called [*hard links*](http://foldoc.org/hard%20link), since there is something else called [a "soft" or "symbolic" link](http://foldoc.org/symbolic%20link)). Each link has exactly one name and location. A file's links are *links to the inode*.
- A file's inode contains [a count of how many links to it currently exist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_link#Link_counter). When a new link is created, this count is [incremented](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Increment_and_decrement_operators); when a link is removed, it is decremented. When it is decremented to zero -- that is, when the last link is removed -- *then* the file has been deleted.
- The [`ln`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/ln.1.html) (without `-s`), `cp -l`, and [`link`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/link.1.html) commands create an additional link to an existing file. For example, `link file1.txt file2.txt` requires that a link `file1.txt` already exist and that no link `file2.txt` exist, and it creates a new link `file2.txt` to the same file that `file2.txt` links to. Most of the time it is sufficient to say that "`file2.txt` is a link to `file1.txt`." It is equally correct to say, "`file1.txt` is a link to `file2.txt`." Internally neither points to the other, but instead both point to the same inode.
- The [`rm`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/rm.1.html) and [`unlink`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/unlink.1.html) commands remove links. When we run `rm foo`, we tend to think of this as deleting `foo`, but no data in a file is lost and no disk space corresponding to the file is freed until *all* links to a file are removed. Often a file has just one link, but not always.

  (Remember, however, that a symbolic link is *not* the same thing as a hard link. A symlink to a file does *not* prevent data loss when the file is deleted!)

#### Making Another Link to a File

To successfully experiment with hard links, you can ensure `file1.txt` does exist and `file2.txt` does not exist. Then when you run `link file1.txt file2.txt`, you will have two links, `file1.txt` and `file2.txt`. When you run `ls -li` you will see that they have the same inode number.

Now `file1.txt` and `file2.txt` are the same file.

Finally, you may want to use `ln` instead of `link`. The [`ln` command](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/ln.1.html) is more [commonly used](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_idiom), [safeguards against some errors](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/303143/what-is-the-difference-between-the-link-and-ln-commands), and, on some systems, has nicer error messages. (When you use the `ln` command *without* the `-s` flag, it creates hard links, as does the `link` command. Passing the `-s` flag causes to create a symbolic link instead.)

#### Further Reading

- [Why do hard links exist?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20670/why-do-hard-links-exist)
- [What happens when you delete a hard link?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/50179/what-happens-when-you-delete-a-hard-link)
- [Why are hard links to directories not allowed in UNIX/Linux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22394/why-are-hard-links-to-directories-not-allowed-in-unix-linux)
- [How to tell which file is original if hard link is created](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/122333/how-to-tell-which-file-is-original-if-hard-link-is-created)
- [What is the difference between a symbolic link and a hard link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185899/what-is-the-difference-between-a-symbolic-link-and-a-hard-link) (Stack Overflow)
- [What is the difference between a hard link and a symbolic link?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/108771/what-is-the-difference-between-a-hard-link-and-a-symbolic-link) (Ask Ubuntu)
- [What is a Superblock, Inode, Dentry and a File?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4402/what-is-a-superblock-inode-dentry-and-a-file)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you added that text.  If you typed `echo foo >> file`, you still have a single file.  Some text editors will delete the original file or rename it to make a backup, which will break the link or leave the link connecting to the backup.

Comment: If I understand correctly `link` and `ln` without any options will do the same thing, create a hard link, pointing to the same inode. You can see that with the command `ls -iltr file1.txt file2.txt`. You explain in the answer, that some tools will delete the original file or rename it to make a backup and use a new inode for the edited file. Please tell us which tool will work like that, and if possible, a tool that 'preserves the hard link to the file name (and not to a backup file)'.

Comment: I cannot catalog the behavior of all tools.  Experiment with the tools available to you.  If the tool makes a backup copy, it probably breaks the link.

Comment: I did not ask for a catalog of all tools, only two examples, one that 'breaks the link', and one that 'preserves' it.

Comment: Here are some obvious choices: "echo > onefilename" and "echo >> otherfilename" will preserve the links, either replacing or appending the contents. vi (really vim.tiny) preserves the links.  "sed -i" (surprisingly) breaks the links.