# Allow older version of python

Tags: python, anaconda

When installing pydot, conda wants me to have an older version of python. How can I fix this? Will this package not work with my current python version?

```
conda install pydot
Fetching package metadata .........
Solving package specifications: .
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - pydot -> pyparsing 1.5.6 -> python 3.3*
  - python 3.5*
Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

python3-pydot is in the default Ubuntu repositories in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu and can be quickly and easily installed without being in conflict with the default system version of Python. Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pydot
```

The default location of dot_parser.py is `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dot_parser.py`. The default location of pydot.py is `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pydot.py`. You can use [symbolic links](https://askubuntu.com/questions/108771/what-is-the-difference-between-a-hard-link-and-a-symbolic-link) to tell conda the paths to these files. Put the symbolic links in conda's own `lib/python3.5/site-packages` directory which for you would be something like: `/home/rik/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages` if rik is your username.

Comment: will this install it in the correct directory for conda or do I need to specify?

Comment: The default location of *dot_parser.py* is `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dot_parser.py`. The default location of *pydot.py* is `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pydot.py`. You can use [symbolic links](https://askubuntu.com/questions/108771/what-is-the-difference-between-a-hard-link-and-a-symbolic-link) to tell conda the paths to these files.

Comment: Where would you put these links?

Comment: Put them in conda's own `lib/python3.5/site-packages` directory which for you would be something like: `/home/Rik/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages` if Rik is your username.