# Matplotlib not found in Anaconda virtualenv, Ubuntu 20

Tags: package-management, python, 20.04, pip, matplotlib

I cannot get matplotlib to work under a virtualenv in Ubuntu 20.04.

```
(myenv) $ pip3 install matplotlib
Requirement already satisfied: matplotlib in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (3.1.2)
(myenv) $ pip3 list | grep matplotlib
matplotlib              3.1.2         
(myenv) $ python3
Python 3.8.2 (default, Mar 26 2020, 15:53:00) 
[GCC 7.3.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Reading /home/user1/.pythonrc
readline is in /home/user1/apps/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload/readline.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
>>> import matplotlib
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'
>>>
```

But it works under the `base` virtualenv

```
(base) $ python3
Python 3.7.6 (default, Jan  8 2020, 19:59:22) 
[GCC 7.3.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Reading /home/user1/.pythonrc
readline is in /home/user1/apps/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/readline.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
>>> import matplotlib
>>>
```

Note the different python versions.
I don't recall doing any upgrade, I simply create `myenv` with `conda create -n myenv`.

I find it puzzling.
**How can I fix this?**

Comment: Yes. I actually did that. I added some more possibly relevant context.

Comment: OK so it's really "matplotlib not found in anaconda virtualenv" then?

Comment: Or create a symbolic link to the existing matplotlib: [Allow older version of python](https://askubuntu.com/q/922154)