# Installed Spyder3 in but get Spyder2

Tags: software-installation, anaconda, spyder

I've installed spyder3 using:

```
sudo apt install spyder3
```

but it loads spyder2 with the splashscreen, etc.

How can I load/install Spyder3? I have Ubuntu 16.04, anaconda 4.2, python 3.5, universe is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

In 16.04,`spyder` is spyder 2.3.8 for **python 2** and `spyder3` is spyder 2.3.8 for **python 3** ([source](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=spyder)). In Zesty the package sources have Spyder 3.1.3, you can [download](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/spyder) and try to install it manually. From Zesty on, the package names will be less confusing here: `python-spyder` for spyder for python 2 and `python3-spyder` for spyder for python 3. However, no release has different versions of spyder in the package sources.

Comment: when I hit "conda list" into terminal it returns:  
  
`spyder                    3.2.1                    py35_0`

Which seems to suggest to me I do have the third version already, the result is the same when I hit "pip list". So i'm not sure where it is loading the spyder 2 from?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [symbolic links](https://askubuntu.com/questions/108771/what-is-the-difference-between-a-hard-link-and-a-symbolic-link) to tell conda the paths to Python files that were installed by apt. The executable file for spyder3 is installed by apt to `/usr/bin/spyder3`. Put the symbolic links in conda's own `lib/python3.5/site-packages` directory which for you would be something like: `/home/0_o/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages` if 0_o is your username.