# Where is pypy for python 3.5 on bionic (18.04 LTS)?

Tags: apt, software-installation, 18.04, python, python3

The package `pypy` in bionic is compatible with Python 2.7.13 (5.10.0+dfsg-3build2, Feb 06 2018, 18:37:50)

I see no "pypy3" in bionic.
I see a snap for pypy3, but only the edge version is up-to-date with code that can run, e.g., pandas (version >= 5.9)

I would prefer an apt package, and would assume that there would be more focus on pypy3 than pypy for python 2, but I'm either missing something, or that isn't true.
What's up?

Comment: Do any of the packages in https://launchpad.net/~pypy/+archive/ubuntu/ppa have python3? The PPA seems to be from the same people maintaining the official package, so you could try emailing them.

Comment: "any reason that it would be handled differently than the python 2 version." - pypy is in universe, so it's maintained by volunteers, and presumably nobody volunteered.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Results of `snap find pypy3` :

```
Name   Version  Publisher    Notes    Summary  
pypy3  5.8.0    pypyproject  classic  PyPy is a fast, compliant alternative implementation of the Python language
```

Installing the native pypy3 snap package with `sudo snap install pypy3 --classic` is the most secure way to install PyPy3.5 in Ubuntu, and it also is updated automatically or can be updated manually with `sudo snap refresh pypy3`. The current version of the pypy3 snap package is 5.10.1.

Version 6.0 of the pypy3 snap package is not yet available, but it will be available as a snap package eventually. Meanwhile the native pypy3 snap package (PyPy3.5 <s>v5.8</s> v5.10.1) is able to run pandas.

---

Download PyPy3.5 v6.0 from the official PyPy website [here](https://pypy.org/download.html).

#### Installation instructions

All binary versions are packaged in a **tar.bz2** or zip file. When uncompressed, they run in-place. For now you can uncompress them either somewhere in your home directory or, say, in `/opt`, and if you want, put a [symlink](https://askubuntu.com/questions/108771/what-is-the-difference-between-a-hard-link-and-a-symbolic-link) from somewhere like `/usr/local/bin/pypy` to `/path/to/pypy_expanded/bin/pypy`. Do not move or copy the executable pypy outside the tree – put a symlink to it, otherwise it will not find its libraries.

Comment: I think it is dangerous to recommend to Ubuntu users that they download binaries, especially a specific (soon-to-be-old) version of a binary, when managed packages (apt, snap, etc) are available. Raw binaries are useful for some distros that don't package pypy, in which case a link to their [generic download page](https://pypy.org/download.html) is much better. Can you change to that link, and list snap first in this answer (since 5.8.0 does run pandas, as requested), pointing out the security benefits of using snap or apt packages when available (automatic security updates etc.)?

Comment: Thanks! And I note 5.10.1 is now available as a snap, and should run pandas etc.

Answer (score 2):

In the [PyPy PPA](https://launchpad.net/~pypy/+archive/ppa).

It wasn't packaged for the main archive, yet, in time for the 18.04 release.

### Installation instructions

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pypy/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install pypy3
```

Comment: Thanks!  Which is more likely to get security updates more reliably and quickly, the ppa or the snap?

Comment: I upload to the PPA pretty soon after the release. I've recently taken over the snap, too, and will do that too.