# What is the best solution when use soft link?

Tags: symbolic-link

I have a tool.
This tool extracts an executable file (called binA) and then this tool call `./binA`
binA file is in where is the same tool's location.
I make a soft link to this tool run anywhere:

```
ln -s /home/user/Desktop/tool /usr/local/bin
```

This tool extracted successfully but can't call ./binA
I tried call  `ln -s /home/user/Desktop/tool /usr/local/bin` this tool can't extract binA file.

What is the best solution for this problem?

Comment: Possible solutions to help:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/108771/what-is-the-difference-between-a-hard-link-and-a-symbolic-link

Comment: Sorry, I know difference between them but how to resolve my problem, either soft link and hard link both don't resolve this case.

Comment: I used a soft link but I can't call ./binA

Comment: Did you make your file `binA` executable, so that you can run it, when you call it directly from the directory, where is is located: `./binA` ? In that case a symbolic link to it should also make it run. An alternative is to move the file `binA` to a directory in `PATH`, for example `/usr/local/bin`