# How do I select a USB drive folder for an application output?

Tags: 18.04, usb, redirect

I'm attempting to install a new app on an Ubuntu 18.04 system.  I want to redirect the files outputted to a USB drive, rather than on my SSD.

eg:

```
 /var/snap/sabnzbd/common/Downloads/incomplete
```

to

```
 31 gb /Downloads/incomplete
```

(where 31 GB) is the ubuntu assigned name of the USB drive.

I KNOW this MUST be awfully silly sounding question, but I am a TOTAL nube

Answer (score 0):

In this specific case the easiest solution is likely to modify a configuration option in the SABnzb program you're using:

https://sabnzbd.org/wiki/configuration/2.3/folders

These configuration changes make the program write it's files in different places, such as your USB drive.

But, what if a program doesn't have a configuration option like that? In that case you would either *mount* or *link* part of the filesystem to a different part of the file system:

- Mounting involves taking a device (such as a USB drive) and placing it's contents somewhere into the file system. For example, your root file system `/` is *mounted* from your SSD device currently. If you wished you could modify the `/etc/fstab` to have your USB device mounted to `/var/snap/sabnzbd/common` or similar.
- Linking involves using the `ln` utility to *link* one area of the drive to another. In this case your USB device is likely already *mounted* to `/media/something` and you can create a symbolic link (called a symlink or sometimes called a "soft" link) from one part of it to another. In this case you would make a directory inside your USB drive then link it to `/var/snap/sabnzbd/common` or similar. Note, you would first probably want to copy that information to the USB drive. See [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/108771/what-is-the-difference-between-a-hard-link-and-a-symbolic-link) if you're interested in the differences between "soft" and "hard" links.