# How to prevent files from being removed when I remove them from a linked directory?

Tags: files, directory, symbolic-link

To create symlinks I use:

```
ln -s /folder /target
```

But when I delete a file from `/target` it also get removed from `/folder`. However I want to keep the file in `/folder` even though I remove it from `/target`. How can I do that?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/108771/what-is-the-difference-between-a-hard-link-and-a-symbolic-link has all you need to know about this. Short version: drop the `-s` so you use a hardlink ( @ravexina )

Answer (score 2):

#### That's the default and correct behavior.

As you know, `/target` is just a symbolic link to `/folder`.  When you go inside `/target`, the files you see are actually living inside `/folder`. **These are actual files and not symbolic links**. So when you delete them, you are deleting the actual files living in `/folder`.

In other words, creating a symlink to a directory does not creates a link for each file/directory inside that directory.

---

#### What to do?

Now we know that we have to create a symbolic link for each and every file in "folder". To do that use `cp`:

```
cp -rs /folder /target
```

or as mentioned in the comments to get hard links:

```
cp -rl /folder /target
```

You can also use `lnddir`.

Comment: I'm not sure if OP not rather wants hard links , `cp -rl ...` ?

Comment: I'm not sure about that, the question was not so clear (take a look at edit history), it mentioned symlinks so I went with that.

Comment: Thank you for editing, sir. Yes, I mean like that. But I want to use a symlink, not `cp` because the directory is updated every day.