# Associate home folder with file drive

Tags: 12.04

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to create a soft or symbolic link?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56339/how-to-create-a-soft-or-symbolic-link)

I am new to ubuntu and wondering how I can associate the tags in the home folder (pictures, doc etc) to my files on a disk partition.  I can easily do that in Win 7 but so far I can only find it under 'devices' in Ubuntu. Thanks, Chris

Comment: Could you better explain this? You mean to auto sort file types to specific folders?

Comment: You may want symbolic links: http://askubuntu.com/questions/56339/how-to-create-a-soft-or-symbolic-link

Comment: In Windows you have the library and clicking on it will take you to the files even if they are on a different drive.  Ubuntu has the home folder with Doc, Music, pic folders but they are empty. How can these folder be linked to where I have the files stored (e drive)?

Answer (score 0):

Use Symlink

`ln -s 'location to link to' 'name of symlink'`

For example:

`ln -s /media/ExternalDrive  ~/Documents/`