# How can I install nbconvert?

Tags: installation, command-line, environment-variables

I tried installing [nbconvert](https://github.com/ipython/nbconvert) via the instructions on their readme.  The `curl` line and the `pip install` line worked flawlessly, but I can't decipher what is meant by:

> You will need to either put the source repository in your `$PATH` or
>   symlink the nbconvert.py script, as well as the css and js
>   subdirectories to a directory in your `$PATH`.

Any idea where `pip` installed the app?  What's this business about `$PATH`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/60218/how-to-add-a-directory-to-my-path

Comment: @EliahKagan, this is a two-part question (semi)specific to nbconvert.

Comment: That makes sense. If this can be answered specifically to this situation, we may as well keep it open. Is [Lucio's answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/237975/22949) sufficient to your needs? If so, I recommend accepting it (and perhaps upvoting it as well).

Answer (score 3):

First, download the source and keep it in a folder where you will not move it.

Second, you need to [create a symbolik link](https://askubuntu.com/q/56339/62483) between  the `nbconvert.py` file, the `css` and `js` directories to your [`$PATH` variable](https://askubuntu.com/q/60218/62483) with the following command:

`sudo ln -s /path_of_source/nbconvert.py /path_of_source/css/ /path_of_source/js/ /usr/bin/`

**Or**

```
cd /path_of_source/
echo "export PATH=\$PATH:nbconvert.py:js:cdd" >> ~/.profile
reset
```

Now you will be available to execute the software from the terminal with `nbconvert`

Comment: tried adding nbconvert to my `PATH` using your second method, but I'm still getting an `No command 'nbconvert' found` message.  I'm still unclear on the symlink approach.  In your example command, should I be located in the `nbconvert` base directory, such that my command would look like `sudo ln -s ./nbconvert.py ./css/ ./js/ /usr/bin`?

Comment: Mmmm, first of all, *that* command is wrong, because you are prepending a dot to the files and that is not good (`./file`).

Comment: @blz I've created a [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7041/room-for-lucio-and-blz) to put information and keep a better communication.. Please, go there to see my messages.