# Syncing Ubuntu and Window fiesystems

Tags: sync

I just downloaded Ubuntu, but I am having some problems.

I can access my old windows files but only by going under the host directory in the file system. I would like to sync up the two fie systems, so my old documents show up in the documents folder for ubuntu and ect.

Is this possible? I'm sure it has to be possible somehow. Any help would be greatly appreciated, keep in mind I'm still a beginner at this sort of thing.

Answer (score 1):

This may be a possibility: 
http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-827081.html

using rsync. 
Another option is making a symbolic link

[How to create a soft or symbolic link?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56339/how-to-create-a-soft-or-symbolic-link)

Hope that helps. Eventually, though, the best option is to migrate fully. I know, it's hard to jump ship, but once you can fully live there, you won't want to go back.

Now, that may not answer your question about the filesystems. That could be another kettle of fish to do the filesystems because they are completely different (ntfs/ext4).