# Folder permissions keep reverting back and won't keep changes

Tags: 12.04

I am trying to change permissions on one of my folders where my website is being ran from for Apache, and I am using a small game framework called ImpactJS, the tile editor for this requires PHP I believe, and because i am not able to read/write to the said folder the tile creator is not functioning correctly.

Everytime I navigate to the folder using the GUI to change the folder permissions they automatically revert back to what they originally were within seconds, this folder is in my user folder, I have even tried changing the permissions as gsku nautilus, same thing happens.

Any help would be great,

I will say this issue with the tile creator didnt appear until just a few minutes ago. It was originally working.

Answer (score 0):

You could try serving your files from the /var/www/your-site folder

And then add yourself to the www-data group.

Run this with your user-name

```
$ sudo usermod -a -G www-data your-user
```

You should be able to change permissions at will then.

If you want your site files to stay in you home folder you can symlink them to the /var/www/ folder.

[How to create a soft or symbolic link?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56339/how-to-create-a-soft-or-symbolic-link)