# Want to write command in terminal and open application

Tags: 14.04, gnome-terminal, matlab, paths

i just installed Matlab on my ubuntu 14.04 and i can open it just with terminal writing full path, but i want to open terminal and write only "matlab" to start that program without writing full path. thanks

Comment: Maybe you want to look at it : http://superuser.com/questions/299872/can-i-shorten-my-directory-commands-in-ubuntu And the most popular answer : http://superuser.com/a/299874

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably best solution will be creating soft symbolic link to `/usr/bin`.

Just type into terminal `sudo ln -s <full_path_to_matlab> /usr/bin/matlab`, and thats all.

[How to create a soft symbolic link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56339/how-to-create-a-soft-or-symbolic-link)

Comment: Well... I have a question x) I always used `ln -s fullpath symlink` and it works, why is that ? oO

Comment: @MrVaykadji: yeah, sorry, I didn't notice this fault :)