# 14.04 strange behavior of desktop icons

Tags: gnome, icons, desktop-icons

Gnome desktop icon in terminal:

```
gnome-desktop-item-edit ~/Pulpit/ --create-new
```

and I have icon on my desktop, it works, but I can not move this item in other place of desktop,
is there any solution for this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T) and run:

```
cd Desktop
```

and then:

```
rm abc.desktop
```

This will remove the icon

Now go to the app and drag and drop it to desktop or create a symbolic link of that particular program

This is how you create a symbolic link

[How to create a soft or symbolic link?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56339/how-to-create-a-soft-or-symbolic-link)