# How to create folder shortcut in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, filesystem, configuration, gui, shortcuts

I have a folder in my Dropbox and I want to add a shortcut of that folder on my Desktop. I guess this should be extremely easy as in Windows OS :) However, I have no idea how to do it in Ubuntu 14.04.

Is there anything I can do to create a simple folder shortcut on my desktop?

Comment: You have two option to create shortcut. First right click on folder and hit make link .You can use terminal sudo ln -s (folder path) (where you want to create shortcut)

Comment: thanks a lot @sohel4r. I'll probably use the "make link" option

Comment: @sohel4r Why use `sudo` for a simple link? Also, another option would be to press Ctrl+Shift and drag the folder to the Desktop.

Comment: @muru Well You install apache then you want to link www folder .So What will you use .Think you want to make a link but you have't global permission  of that folder .how will you make a link.I am know very poor in Linux.If i am wrong then teach me .

Comment: @sohel4r Well, he's not making a link in a root-owned folder, but to his own Desktop. Use sudo when you absolutely **have** to, not when you feel like it. As a sysadmin, I frequently get emails about users who try to use `sudo` when it is absolutely unnecessary, like the case you made just now. The right way to go about accessing folders of servers (like `/var/www/` is to add yourself to the server's group (`www-data`, in this case), and make the folder group-writable.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Click on that folder, click on make link, then move the shortcut to Desktop.

Comment: But when we click on that folder from desktop, there is no UP folder,back **<** takes to `home/desktop/` folder

Comment: Some of files, to which you don't have root privileges, won't work.

Comment: There's no make link option in Ubuntu 18

Answer (score 109):

it simple: just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> and drag.

Comment: A little short, but definitely an answer imho.

Comment: This worked for me in two cases 1) creating a link to a separate internal hard drive (not the system disk) where Make Link was grayed-out, 2) For a directory on NAS storage where the Make Link gave an error, "This target doesn't support symbolic links".

Comment: This **is** the answer.  The other answers either resort to CLI or **don't work**.  A short answer is fine.

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+Legendary

Comment: This is handy, because I don't have an option in the right click context menu on folder - however is there a way how to add it to the context menu ?

Comment: @jave.web Yes -- use the application menu (either at the top left of your screen or a colourful icon next to the window controls) to go to your Nautilus preferences, then under "Behavior" enable link creation.

Comment: I'm using pcmanfm, but even if I run nautilus I see no such option :/ After editing Behavior preferences, I do see new context menu option "create link", however created link acts as alternative path - it does not open linked path, it creates something like a mounted folder.

Comment: Works also on "Linux Fedora 28"

Comment: This doesnt work in Ubuntu 18

Comment: @PhilipRego I must disagree, works on Ubuntu 18 - both *nautilus* and *nemo* ...

Comment: @jave.web Doesn't work on the Desktop. That's probably what I was trying.

Comment: @PhilipRego  well that's what I mean, it works for me on Desktop just fine - well creating the link there - do you mean within the Desktop itself?

Comment: Best way to create folder shortcut, no hectic of another dependency

Comment: Did not work on Desktop. Further, the link created this way does not take you to the folder. The solution provided @tseabrook is a good solution.

Comment: Big tks. It works on Vmware host, Raspi sytem.

Answer (score 16):

You can read full details here

```
man ln

ln -s /usr/bin/bar /opt/foo
```

also see this link 
[Create a soft or symbolic link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56339/how-to-create-a-soft-or-symbolic-link)

Comment: That's wrong. That's only for files. You give no explanation and link to a different question. And why would you create a shortcut with a different name than the folder.

Comment: For Ubuntu 20.04 it works flawless. I used it to create a link in Desktop of an regular User; this link points to a NAS drive folder. It displays the Folder, Name and the North-East purple arrow, in my regular Ubuntu theme. Of course I had to set permissions first.

Comment: thanks. this let me create a shortcut of a folder on linux.

Answer (score 6):

I wasn't able to file a reliable solution from the other provided answers. As such, I'm sharing my preferred approach to creating a desktop shortcut.

Desktop shortcuts can be added by creating a file with the .desktop extension in the `~/Desktop/` folder using any text editor. The .desktop file we create shall launch the folder viewer app `xdg-open` at the location specified by `[folder-path]`.

Though it's not necessary, it is of course sensible to name the file similarly to the folder name.

The following information should be written to `~/Desktop/[file-name].desktop`:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=[folder-name]
Exec=xdg-open [folder-path]
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Icon=[icon-path]
```

Replacing `[folder-name]` with the name of the folder and `[folder-path]` with the location of the folder.

Please Note: If the location or name of the folder changes then the .desktop entry will require to be edited.

Once the file has been created it shall appear on the desktop. Right click it and click `Allow Launching` to activate the .desktop file as an application.

You can replace `[icon-path]` with an image of your choice; Default Ubuntu icons are located at: `/usr/share/icons/`.

Examples of default Ubuntu folder icons include (but are not limited to):

- `/usr/share/icons/Yaru/48x48/places/folder.png`
- `/usr/share/icons/Humanity/places/48/folder.svg`
- `/usr/share/icons/HighContrast/48x48/folder.png`

For more information on the Desktop Entry Specification please see:
https://developer.gnome.org/desktop-entry-spec/

Note that as our file is launching `xdg-open` it is proper to use the .desktop extension, rather than the .directory extension.

Comment: I think this is what most people will need. Solved my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently this **is** handled correctly from the GUI :-)  (14.04 LTS)
(Move to Trash, Empty Trash)

But **generally**: When you have a **link** to a directory, **be VERY sure to delete ONLY the link** should/when you come to that point.

From terminal, the correct thing to do is:

```
rm LINK-TO-DIR
```

BUT NOT:

```
rm -r LINK-TO-DIR
```

... which will first delete the files/dirs that the link MAKES VISIBLE,
and even more so with the "-f" flag.

If you are a "Terminal" user, have a look on the output of

```
ln --help
```

... that ls lover case of LN nothing else ;-)

The syntax for it may seem a tad "backwards" at first as you FIRST specify where it should point, then the name of your LINK.

```
cd $HOME/Desktop
mkdir -p $HOME/z
ln -s $HOME/z New-Link-To-Home-z
```

... note that the GUI **will not** notice the new Desktop content without help; you need to logout+login.

More info on the 'net or slightly terse in either of

```
man ln
info ln
```

... where I personally prefer the first because 'info' has a tendency to 'slip out of context'.

Answer (score 1):

Basically there are two options and both of them work with Ubuntu 22.04 and probably previous releases too, 
You can create a link to your Dropbox folder by running this command in terminal

```
ln -s <path_to_reference_folder> <path_where_you_want_your_link_to_be_placed>
```

You can also do it through pressing Ctrl+Shift+M after selecting the folder you want a shortcut of, it will create a link to that folder in the reference folder's parent folder, then you can press Ctrl+Shift and drag the link_to_your_folder to desktop or wherever you want that to be placed.

> Note: Just doing Ctrl+Shift and drag, as some people suggested here, won't create a shortcut of your folder instead it would move your folder to desktop which you probably don't want to do as this isn't the way shortcuts work in Windows.

Have a Nice Day...!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I'm so late to the conversation but if you are trying to navigate to a folder or run any common command with ease you want to create aliases. First you need to open the alias editor.

```
sudo nano -Bu ~/.bashrc
```

go all the way to the bottom of the opened document and add the following

```
#My aliases
alias aliasname='command you want issued here'
```

in my editor I added these 2 lines to make it easier to access and edit my aliases.

```
alias makealias='sudo nano -Bu ~/.bashrc'
alias refreshalias='. ~/.bashrc'
```

after your aliases have been created issue the refreshalias command I made

```
. ~/.bashrc
```

now test your alias by entering your keyword and see if it creates correctly.

Something that surprised me the first time I did this was the fact that 3 common file directory tools taught to me in school ll, la, and l were all aliases of ls extentions in this same tool.

```
alias ll='ls -alF'
alias la='ls -A'
alias l='ls -CF'
```

as a note to me I also created an aliaslist.txt file on my home with every alias I made with a description after it. Have fun building aliases hope they help you as much as they help me.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me `-r` option to make the shortcut relative to its source. Without it, you may have error as

> The link "shortcut-name" is broken

```
ln -rs /path/to/create/shortcut-name /path/to/the/source
```

Comment: This is the same as solhel4r’s answer from several years ago 

Comment: This was helpful to me... I kept wondering why my link was broken on and on... Thanks ;)

Answer (score -1):

These below command will create file or folder shortcut in your working directory, in this case it's Desktop/.

```
cd Desktop/
ln -s /path/to/source/file-or-folder
```