# How to create a desktop shortcut

Tags: 16.04, gnome

Can somebody please explain to me how to create a desktop shortcut to an application like Chrome or Blender as if I'm an idiot? I really don't get it. I have the gnome panel program thing and can run it (see image) but after that I'm lost.

[image: PIC RELATED]

Comment: Here's my preferred method, with a detailed example using the Arduino IDE v1.8.5: https://askubuntu.com/a/1014261/327339

Comment: **No headache solution:** "it simple: just press `Ctrl + Shift` and drag." (the folder to the desktop area) , thanks goes here: https://askubuntu.com/a/691976/277898

Answer (score 70):

You have to install `gnome-panel` package which comes up with ability to create a application launcher on the desktop or wherever you like. Add `--no-install-recommends` suffix to prevent other package that aren't necessary.

```
sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends gnome-panel
```

After installing `gnome-panel`, use following command to create a launcher.

```
gnome-desktop-item-edit --create-new ~/Desktop
```

Once you execute the above command, create launcher application will be opened.

[image]

- In **Type field** "Application" will be a default value. If you're creating launcher for application which has no gui, that runs in terminal like VIM editor then you need to select "Application in Terminal".
- In **Name field** type application name.
- In **Command field** type the executable command which open your application.
- **Comment field** is optional.

To set icon, click on the small box on the top left side near name field and choose a image for it. Click "OK" if you are done.

Comment: Note the language localization: on spanish Ubuntu v16.04 you must use `gnome-desktop-item-edit --create-new ~/Escritorio` or the command will fail.

Comment: This will no longer work for Ubuntu 20.04. When I try this I get the following error: `gnome-desktop-item-edit: command not found`

Comment: now working in `Ubuntu 20.*` `gnome-desktop-item-edit: command not found`

Comment: It appears that `gnome-desktop-item-edit` was removed from `gnome-panel` in 19.10: https://askubuntu.com/a/1184737/457041

Comment: How can we do it for all users on system?

Comment: How can you place this desktop shortcut in the Dock?

Answer (score 17):

Complete instructions can be found in the answers to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64222/how-can-i-create-launchers-on-my-desktop).  Here's the really simple version:

1. Launch Nautilus (the file manager).
2. In Nautilus, click on `Computer`.
3. From there, navigate to `/usr/share/applications`.
4. Find the icon of the program you want a shortcut for, click on it, and type **Ctrl+C** to copy.
5. In Nautilus, click on `Desktop` in the left pane.
6. Type **Ctrl+V** to copy the shortcut to the desktop.
7. Right-click your new shortcut, click `Properties`, click on the `Permissions` tab, and make sure that the `Allow executing file as program` box is ticked.
8. X out of the `Properties` dialog and also out of Nautilus.  Enjoy your new desktop shortcut!

Edit: @DanDascalescu is right, this method just copies the executable rather than creating a shortcut.  **Please don't use this method.**  Sorry folks!

Comment: If you find my answer helpful, please consider upvoting or accepting it.

Comment: This just copy the program completely to desktop AFAIU

Comment: This doesn't create a shortcut, this copies the executable to ~/Desktop. How does this answer have so many upvotes?

Comment: didn't work, gives an error "The executable launcher was unable to locate it's companion library"

Comment: @DanDascalescu, NO, this does not copy an executable. If you look at the file properties, you will see it says - "Desktop configuration file". If you open it with a text editor, you will see that it is a typical shortcut.

Comment: @rclocher3, DanDascalescu is wrong.

Comment: works if the installer made a shortcut in the install folder that you can copy to desktop folder

Answer (score 12):

To create a launcher on the Desktop:

1) You need gksu so if you don't have it yet, run in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install gksu
```

2) Run gedit (or any other text editor) and then enter the info below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Icon[en_US]=/opt/lampp/htdocs/favicon.ico
Name[en_US]=XAMPP
Exec=gksu /opt/lampp/manager-linux-x64.run
Comment[en_US]=Start XAMPP Control Panel
Name=XAMPP
Comment=Start XAMPP Control Panel
Icon=/opt/lampp/htdocs/favicon.ico
Save the file on your Desktop as Xampp.desktop
```

3) Once the shortcut is on the Desktop, right-click on it, go to Properties, Permissions tab, and check 'Allow executing file as program'

The above creates a shortcut for XAMPP control panel.

Comment: Why is gksu required?

Comment: What's that icon path? How do I get the icon from an executable?

Comment: gksu is not required

Comment: gksu is required to run/execute the file `Exec=gksu /opt/lampp/manager-linux-x64.run` check 8th line!