# How to put Chrome shortcut on Desktop?

Tags: google-chrome

I tried to drag the Google Chrome icon onto my desktop. This didn't work. How can I put a shortcut to Chrome on the desktop?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add more info, for example Ubuntu flavour and version etc.

Comment: .... and, what do you mean by "adding to the desktop".... ?
Also, this /may/ help....  https://askubuntu.com/a/854379/683272

Comment: I Mean By Putting On The Desktop. SORRY

Comment: Please answer Posmky's question. It is very relevant.

Comment: To start with, which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) , and which release number? Are you using virtualization, and if so, which package? Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please do not use Add Comment.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I create launchers on my desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64222/how-can-i-create-launchers-on-my-desktop)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All I did was, go to

`/home/otiswong/.local/share/applications/chrome-nmmhkkegccagdldgiimedpiccmgmieda-Default.desktop`

and copy and paste it into the desktop

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me on Ubuntu 17.10. Please modify the path as necessary.

```
cp /usr/share/applications/chromium-browser.desktop /home/<username>/Desktop/
```

and then

```
chmod 750 /home/<username>/Desktop/chromium-browser.desktop
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to basically follow the steps described by google:

1. click menu -> more tools -> create shortcut
2. your tab will close and shortcut will be put on desktop
3. RIGHT-CLICK the shortcut, and click "Allow Launching"

it should update icon and should work.

Answer (score 0):

Create a desktop application launcher as explained in answers to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/854373/how-to-create-a-desktop-shortcut).

Then right click on launcher and select **Properties**. Under the **Basic** tab enter `google-chrome` (verify this command by entering it in terminal) as **command** and close the properties. That's all.

Comment: Doesn't Work, Because I Don't Have A Properties Option