# Cant find app in menu of Lubuntu 19.04

Tags: lubuntu, lxqt

OS: Lubuntu 19.04

I downloaded SMPlayer for YouTube and want to add it to my taskbar as a shortcut. But there is no icon in the app menu. I just type its name and the app starts.

How to add an icon and how to add to taskbar?

Comment: Please refer this answer https://askubuntu.com/questions/854373/how-to-create-a-desktop-shortcut

Comment: A bit too difficult for me to follow. I dont know the exact name of the app. so how to add it ?  as its not even in my menu,
Plus I can't use terminal well at all

Comment: 'In Command field type the executable command which open your application.''  how on earth am i supposed to know the command?
The app is called SMTube.  I've no idea how to open it by executable command.

Comment: What exactly did you install? Was it `smtube`?

Answer (score 3):

If you installed `smtube`, open your file manager and navigate to ***Computer → File System → usr → share → applications*** and scroll down till you see the *smtube* icon.

[image: smtube in /usr/share/applications]

Then grab it with your mouse and drag it over to your panel.

[image: smtube in panel]

Answer (score 0):

1. Open terminal using <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> and type `smtube`. It should open SMTube.
2. Create a text file with the name ***SMTube.desktop***
3. Paste the following text on it

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
   [Desktop Entry]
   Version=1.0
   Type=Application
   Terminal=false
   Icon[en_US]=/home/subhadipl/Desktop/player.ico
   Name[en_US]=SmTube
   Exec=/usr/bin/smtube
   Comment[en_US]=Start SmTube
   Name=SmTube
   Comment=Start SmTube
   Icon=/home/subhadipl/Desktop/player.ico
   ```

   Change the icon and name as per your choice.
4. keep it on your desktop, right click, and open properties, permission tab and check '*Allow executing file as program*'.

This will create a shortcut for smtube. Hope this helps.

Comment: Installing *smtube* places a .desktop file for *smtube* called *smtube.desktop* (as listed in a terminal) in */usr/share/applications*. In my opinion, there's no need to create one.

Answer (score 0):

I too noticed that sometimes the launcher adds and shows icons and sometimes it does not. Maybe it needs "scrolling" within the menu, maybe it is a bug and maybe it is a feature. I solved it in following manner:

1. Click on launcher icon
2. Right click on category (games,office,system etc.)
3. Choose add to desktop

This adds the whole category to the desktop with all apps shortcuts within, whether they are shown or not. In this method there will be a fixed number of folders on the desktop and no need to add icon shortcuts here and there.