# Create a folder shortcut in ubuntu 17.04

Tags: 17.04, shortcuts

A very simple trouble. I'm using Ubuntu 17.04 and when I do right click to a folder I don't have the option to create a shortcut. Any idea?

I checked the post 
[How to create folder shortcut in Ubuntu 14.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/486461/how-to-create-folder-shortcut-in-ubuntu-14-04) but it doesn't work any of the solutions.

Comment: What happens when you do **Ctrl** + **Shift** +Drag?

Comment: @fakedad Yes it works. I opened /home , then you can Ctrl + Shift the user folder, thanks. At leadt is works for files or folders shortcuts.

Comment: @fakedad: That's what actually worked for me, thanks! The link creation failed with the error that "this location does not support symbolic links". I guess you could also add this as an answer.

Answer (score 13):

Perhaps your nautilus preferences isn't setup, do so with these steps:

1. Open nautilus and place your cursor at the top to see files menu.
2. Click on files and select `preferences` option
3. Go to `Behavior` --> `Link Creation`. There make sure the `Show action to create symbolic links` is `checked`
4. Close that dialog box and try to create that link again.

[image]

Comment: I can't find how to have the menu bar, it doesn't appear.

Comment: That means you haven't set it up to show on the nautilus window, it should be on the system window of Ubuntu!

Comment: Trying to figure out where this settings is. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use:

```
gnome-desktop-item-edit ~/Desktop/ --create-new
```

`gnome-desktop-item-edit` is a command included in the [gnome-panel package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=artful&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=gnome-desktop-item-edit) which you can install either via the software center or the command `sudo apt install gnome-panel` if you don't have it installed. As indicated by the name this package is closely tied to the gnome desktop if you are using a different desktop, attempt this at your own risk.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on desktop, select "Create Launcher"

[image]

on Type selection, please chose "Location" then browse your location folder.