# Installing utorrent

Tags: server, utorrent

When installing and I get to the symbolic link I type in:
sudo ln -s/opt/utorrent-server-alpha-v3_3/utserver /usr/bin/utserver
I get a return of:
ln: invalid option -- '/'
What am I missing? This is my first time exploring linux.

Comment: May I suggest you to use Transmission instead of uTorrent? Transmisson in an open-source, lightweight and user-friendly torrent client for Linux. It has the same features uTorrent does, like downloading from magnet links, .torrent files, etc., and it does not have ads. It's in the official Ubuntu repositories; You can install it from the Software Center (search for Transmission) or simply run `sudo apt-get install transmission-gtk` in a terminal. After installed, search for it in the Dash.

Comment: Please don't create a symbolic link in '/usr/bin' or '/bin'. Those are reserved for Ubuntu packages. If you messes with that, you will eventually get problems updating or installing packages. Instead you should use '/usr/local/bin'. The hierarchy '/usr/local' is reserved for local installations by the computers administrator.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a soft or symbolic link?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56339/how-to-create-a-soft-or-symbolic-link)

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you have an error in your code. Make sure there is a space between `-s` and `/`, otherwise the path to your program will be interpreted as a parameter to the `ln` command. The command line should be like this:

`sudo ln -s /opt/utorrent-server-alpha-v3_3/
utserver /usr/bin/utserver`

Comment: Mark this as answer if it actually helped you.

Comment: @Buddhaman, if this is the answer to your problem then you should probably mark it as such.