# Where does the Virtual Box draw space from for installing a different OS?

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization

In my PC, running on Ubuntu 14.04, the hard disk is divided into several partitions, and although there is vacant space in each of them there is only a paltry 8.7 MB unpartitioned space left.

But recently, after installing the Virtual Box when I attempted to install Windows XP in it, I was offered a 10 GB space for formatting and installing the new OS. Now can anyone tell me where exactly this 10 GB space is being taken from and, more importantly, whether this threatens my data in the various partitions?

Comment: How much space do you have in your home directory? (or wherever you created the associated disk for that VM)

Comment: @muru.  My home directory is of 9.6 GB.

Comment: Then it's likely that when Windows XP  actually gets around to using 10 GB, your home directory will be filled up. Look in the VM settings to see where you have actually stored the virtual disk, and move it to a partition with more than 10 Gb free.

Comment: @muru. I can't figure out where it's stored. Settings>General>Advanced>Snapshot Folder shows: /home/subrata[my name]/VirtualBox VMs/Test/Snapshots. Is it there? The adjacent lowdown gives options of "other" and "reset". Should these be used? Alternatively perhaps I could shrink some of the partitions so as to increase the unpartitioned space and then use THAT space at the time of installing the Windows? My overriding concern is, naturally, not to risk the existing data. So which would be the safe way?

Comment: Try: Settings>Storage, image listed below SATA, and look for Location in the *Information* pane.

Comment: @muru. Settings>Storage takes me to "Controller: IDE" (no SATA), under this is "Test.vdi" with an image. Clicking that image takes me to "Information" which shows "Virtual Size 10 GB" , "Actual Size 3 MB" (which I don't understand), and then perhaps more importantly  "Location:  /home/subrata/VirtualBox VMs/Test/Test.vdi". Does it mean it's there? Should I choose "Cancel"? After that how to assign a different location?

Answer (score 3):

The virtual machine definition itself will occupy little space. The thing that will occupy space is the virtual disk where the client OS will be installed, as long as the possible snapshots you'll take<sup>**1**</sup>.

Normally the disks are installed in a directory called `VirtualBox VMs` under your home; so it will *by default* occupy space in your home partition. Native Virtualbox virtual disks are dinamical; they will grow till occupying the allocated space (10G in your case) when the guest OS will use the space.

To check where you have yor disks, open "settings":

[image]

...as you see, I have mine in another partition --- namely one mounted on `/home/vbox`. To create the virtual disk (VDI) in a non standard place, you simply select the directory where to put it on creation (you can move it later too, in a lot of way, the most easy being to move the containing directory and put a [symlink](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56339/how-to-create-a-soft-or-symbolic-link) in its place).

[image: choosing the VDI location]

The VDI is a file as much as Linux is concerned, so you *cannot* put it in an unallocated space on disk<sup>**2**</sup>, so you have to partition, format and mount your unallocated space beforehand.

---

Footnotes:

<sup>**1**</sup> and it **will** grow up, but it will not grow down --- this is much more complex. In my experience, 10G is far too little for a Windows installation --- especially if you plan to put Office on it.

<sup>**2**</sup> well, you probably can. But it's not a standard way to do it.

Comment: Yours is in home, right? What do I do to shift it to a new  unpartitioned space or  partition of adequate size specially created for this purpose? Do I do it during choosing the Settings of the VM or can I do it during installing the new OS?

Answer (score 2):

> there is only a paltry 8.7 MB unpartitioned space left.

Not important.

> Now can anyone tell me where exactly this 10 GB space is being taken from and, more importantly, whether this threatens my data in the various partitions?

From the partition you installed the virtual machine. The VM makes a file on your system and treats that as a filesytem where you can install an operating system into.

> I was offered a 10 GB space for formatting and installing the new OS

You where also asked WHERE to create the VM. It will probably default to your home (ie. something like `/home/$USER/Virtual Box/Windows XP`).

Comment: I want to move my VM and everything related to it safely away from all existing partitions.  For this I can shrink my existing partitions and create an adequate unpartitoned space and also a new partition. The question is : after doing that, should I assign this location for the VM & new OS while choosing the Settings of the VirtualBox , or can I do it during installing the new OS?

Comment: I would pick the 2nd, Create a big /data/ partition for all your VMs.