# What type of link is this?

Tags: symbolic-link

When I entered following command in my terminal

```
ls -la /etc | grep "\->"
```

I got following list & need to know what type of link is this type

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q7ATo.png]

and kindly guide me how can I create this type of links.

the type of link is different

and i followed following instruction

- created a folder called folder-a
- entered following command ln -sv folder-a folder-b
- and output is displayed as ‘folder-b’ -> ‘folder-a’
- when i type ls - l the color is cyan blue folder-b -> folder-a

but i am expecting above image result

Comment: Symbolic links, usually.

Comment: how to create this type of Symbolic links

Comment: About creating a symbolic link you have article upon this link https://askubuntu.com/questions/56339/how-to-create-a-soft-or-symbolic-link

Comment: Could you please post text files, dialogue messages, and program output listings as text, not as images? To achieve the latter two you can either 1) select, copy & paste the dialogue text or terminal content or 2) [save the program output to a file](//askubuntu.com/q/420981/175814) and use that. Longer listings (the editor will tell you what's too long) should be uploaded to a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) and linked to in the question. Thanks.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly your question is really about the output formatting and colouring of `ls`, not the creation of (symbolic) links. Is that correct? Could you please include the output of `ls -ld folder-a` (as text and, if you need colours, as an image)? What's the output of `readlink folder-a`? If it's `folder-b` then everything is in order.

Comment: @DavidFoerster no actually i read link type so the data is saved in folder-b  only not on folder-a but when i access folder-a the data should be loaded from folder-b
and the output as follows
drwxrwxr-x 2 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Jul 18 06:26 folder-a
 readlink folder-a No output is displayed for this

Comment: I have no clue what you mean. Could you please **[edit]** your question to add this information and include an example? Especially file or program output [listings](/editing-help#code) (with the help of the `{}` button in the editor toolbar) will be much more readable there; alternatively you can use a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) for longer listings and include the link of your pastie in your question. Overall it’s best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When you see the 'redirect' characters `->` in the file list, it is symbolic links, made by `ln -s xxx yyy`. That is is soft links (also called symbolic links) is also shown by the first 'l' in the access-rights.

The other link option is hard links. The number just after the access-rights show how many hard-links there are to a file or directory. To find the other(s) you have to look for files/directories with same inode-number in the same filesystem.

Hard links can only be within the same filesystem. Soft links can cross filesystem borders.

Answer (score 0):

The coimmand is `ln`.  See the [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/ln.1.html) for all details but basically, it has the following form:

```
ln [OPTION]... [-T] TARGET LINK_NAME
```

TARGET is the file you want to be linked, LINK_NAME is the new name.  In your case, `resolv.conf` is the `LINK_NAME` and `../run/resolvconf/resolv.conf`, the `TARGET`.  You should also take into consideration you have physical and symbolic links.

Comment: But that wasn't what was asked about ...

Comment: The op asked ' kindly guide me how can I create this type of links.'