# I am currently trying to install CMake to Ubuntu-20.04 via WSL but I get dependency error

Tags: apt, windows-subsystem-for-linux

So what I did so far was install CMake to configure my CLion so that I can run Valgrind. However, after following a few suggestions, I have encountered this problem and I cannot resolve it.

I installed 3.16 CMake, but I need the newest version of CMake, so I added an apt repo from kitware. But now I am getting the following message when I try to reinstall CMake using apt-get.

I know latest version of Ubuntu include libssl1.1, could that be conflicting with this dependency? how do I let apt detect that I have libssl1.1?

```
rleung@DESKTOP-HV6P4HF:/mnt/c/Users/ryanl$ sudo apt-get install cmake
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 cmake : Depends: libssl1.0.0 (>= 1.0.2~beta3) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
rleung@DESKTOP-HV6P4HF:/mnt/c/Users/ryanl$ apt-cache policy libssl1.0.0
libssl1.0.0:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)

Comment: aptitude also gives me the unmet dependencies error. it says that libssl1.0.0 is a virtual package and is not provided by any available package

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does “Package <package> has no installation candidate” mean?](https://askubuntu.com/q/14685/) Search on the linked question's age for *libssl*.

Comment: I don't see a ppa for libssl1.0.0. I'm not sure which repository I should add for apt-get to find libssl1.0.0

Comment: Ok, I had a closer look, I I have libssl1.1, but apt detects that I still ned libssl even though i have the newer version. How do I configure apt so that it can detect libssl1.1? Is it possible to downgrade the package?

Comment: [Create a symbolic link](https://askubuntu.com/q/56339/) that links libssl1 which isn't installed to libssl1.1 which is installed.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer to this problem with the help of Karel.

inside sources.list, I needed to add the following repository to get libssl1.0.0

What you need to do is go edit your sources.list using your choice of editor, for my example, I use vim

```
sudo vim /etc/apt/sources.list
```

add the following line

```
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main
```

libssl1.0.0 will now be available to get via apt-get.