# Relocate logs in /opt/log to /var/log

Tags: log, syslog

I want to save my logs into `/var/log` so that I can send them to the Siem platform, because the platform is unable to receive them from `/opt/log`. The logs are saved into `/opt/log` because I am using a third party application.

Comment: Maybe create a [symbolic link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56339/how-to-create-a-soft-or-symbolic-link) for `/opt/logs` that points to `/var/log`?

Comment: Maybe the application has a setting log directory?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a symbolic link to point the directory `/opt/log` to `/var/log` instead.

First make a backup copy of `/opt/log`:

```
sudo mv /opt/log /opt/log_backup
```

Then create the link:

```
sudo ln -s /var/log /opt/log
```