How to install an older version of GCC for armhf?
I'm not really an expert of linux, so i'm feeling a bit lost.
I'm running an Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS image in WSL, as i need to cross-compile a program for an ARM linux pc using a Windows PC. That image was automagically installed by the Powershell command WSL.exe --install and i'm fine with it.
I've been able to add the armhf architecture, the gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf and to build my program.
Problem is that the version of GCC is 11 and the glibc is too new for the debian image of the ARM machine.
So i need to downgrade to GCC-10.
I can remove the GCC installed, but then?
How do i install a gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf v10?

GCC 10 packages (including the one you're after) are available in the Universe Repository.
Please see here how to enable the Universe repos.

Thanks, installed. But, sorry if the question is dumb, how do i launch it? i mean: all my makefile calls arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc, but now it doesn't exists, it exists arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc-10. There's a way to make it being the "default" one so i don't have to change all the makefiles?

Check out how symlinks work. https://askubuntu.com/q/56339/1066942
